# problems with boss moving from one side to the other with vector3.lerp

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector

I have a boss that will move from the left side of the screen to the right and it'll go up and down a little as it goes back and forth, it works great until it randomly slows down and starts going back to the other side of the screen before it reaches the point I marked `xwaypoint` and it'll eventually slow down and stop at 0,0 but I have no coding that would make it do that, this has really stumped me to create an account on here, this is the code that is related to this boss moving:

```cs
if (moveAllow == true)
{
    Vector3 horizontalPosition = Vector3.Lerp(xWaypoints[currentWayPointIdex].position, xWaypoints[currentWayPointIdex + 1].position, t);
    float verticalOffset = Mathf.Sin(Time.time * verticalFrequency) * verticalAmplitude;
    transform.position = new Vector3(horizontalPosition.x, horizontalPosition.y + verticalOffset, horizontalPosition.z * 0);
    t += moveSpeedX * direction * Time.deltaTime;
    if (t >= 1.0f || t <= 0.0f)
    {
        direction = -direction;
        currentWayPointIdex += direction;

        currentWayPointIdex = Mathf.Clamp(currentWayPointIdex, 0, xWaypoints.Length - 2);

        t = Mathf.Clamp01(t);
    }
}
```

I have already tried a few things to get it to stay at a constant speed and not stop at the 0,0 mark such as adding a distance from the next `xWaypoint` and if it's not before it'll set `movespeedx` back to 0.1 I could not figure out how to get it to not stop before the `xwaypoints`